# Recursive LINQ to self referenced data table in reverse

Tags: c#, linq

```
| ID | PrID | Name |
|------------------|
|  1 | null | N1   |
|  2 |    1 | N2   |
|  3 |    2 | N3   |
|  4 |    3 | N4   |
```

Hello, I have following self-referenced datatable. My input parameter is N1 and I need to find it's last child N4. Please help to write LINQ query.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar. Basically you need to write an extension method as LINQ was not designed to handle scenarios like this.

[Walking a hierarchy table with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560304/walking-a-hierarchy-table-with-linq)

Answer (score 0):

Not the best LINQ candidate, however, this recursive extension should work:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> fnRecurse)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        yield return item;

        IEnumerable<T> seqRecurse = fnRecurse(item);
        if (seqRecurse != null)
        {
            foreach (T itemRecurse in Traverse(seqRecurse, fnRecurse))
            {
                yield return itemRecurse;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's your sample data:

```
DataTable tbldata = new DataTable();
tbldata.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
tbldata.Columns.Add("PrID", typeof(int));
tbldata.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
tbldata.Rows.Add(1, null, "N1");
tbldata.Rows.Add(2, 1, "N2");
tbldata.Rows.Add(3, 2, "N3");
tbldata.Rows.Add(4, 3, "N4");
```

This query returns your desired result:

```
string parentName = "N1";
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = tbldata.AsEnumerable();
DataRow parentRow = rows.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("Name") == parentName);
DataRow lastChild = null;
if(parentRow != null)
{
    int parentID = parentRow.Field<int>("ID");
    lastChild = rows.Where(r => r.Field<int?>("PrID") == parentID)
        .Traverse(parent => rows
            .Where(child => child.Field<int?>("PrID") == parent.Field<int>("ID")))
        .LastOrDefault();
}
```

Output:

```
Console.Write(String.Join(",", lastChild.ItemArray)); // 4,3,N4
```

Comment: Side-note: this approach does not depend on the order as the sample data suggests (the desired row is already the last). It jumps from parent to child recursively.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably undoable in LINQ.

You can either create a stored procedure that will use `WHILE` loop to find last child or you can pull whole table to your application and resolve it using loop like

```
Item i = FetchFirst();
while (i.GetNext() != null)
    i = i.GetNext();
```

Then `i` will store result. `GetNext()` loads next item, `FetchFirst()` loads N1 item.

Comment: this is not undoable in LINQ but surely, but it might cause performance pitfalls.